# Overloaded C# methods cause Unity crash when calling each other

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I managed to Crash unity, not just my game but the entire editor, when attempting to run this code.

```
public object get(string path, object default_value) {
    string[] parts = path.Split ('.');
    Dictionary<string, object> dict = json_parsed;
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < parts.Length - 1; i++) {
        dict = dict[parts[i]] as Dictionary<string, object>;
    }
    try {
        return dict[parts[i]];
    } catch (KeyNotFoundException) {
        return default_value;
    }
}
public int get(string path, int default_value) {
    return Convert.ToInt32(get(path, default_value));
}
```

The crash happens when running the `get(path, default_value)` code inside the second version of `get()` but I can work around it if I name that second version `getInt()` instead.

I'm new to C# and its been years since I've even used a language with overloading, so exactly what I might be doing wrong here is eluding me.

Comment: can you be more specific when you say it crashes..have you added break points in each of the methods to see why it's crashing.. also can you show what you are passing, also try changing the param type or adding a default param to the one that's not working [C# Method OverLoad tutorial](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

```
public int get(string path, int default_value) {
    return Convert.ToInt32(get(path, default_value));
}
```

this `get` infinitely calls itself which will result in stack overflow.

Change the call to:

```
public int get(string path, int default_value) {
    return Convert.ToInt32(get(path, (object)default_value));
}
```